# Run headphones and speakers?

Tags: pi-zero-w, phat-dac

I have a pi zero w. I was hoping I could run an 8 ohm 0.5 watt speaker from a line level rca output or maybe run the speaker from a 186 ma(ithink???) headphone amplifier? This is from the justboom dac zero pHat. I'm just looking for a way to power the 8 ohm 0.5 watt speaker but then when I plug in headphones the power doesn't blow them. I have one of those cool headphone jacks with the switch in it so when I plug in headphones the speaker turns off. Would love suggestions if what I'm doing won't work. Thanks.

Comment: I think the headphone amplifier is 25 mw according to a website that sells it. I would assume this is not enough to even get sound out of a 0.5w speaker?

Comment: I heard the pimoroni phat DAC can power headphones with the stereo jack but again idk about speakers

Comment: It's a single 0.5w speaker

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

I got the adafruit speaker bonnet instead

My plan is to add resistors before the one mono 8ohm 0.5 watt speaker so that the power does not exceed that of the speaker, my plan is also to do the same for the headphones, and hopefully they work. I would need a big resistor, but I have a pack from radio shack lol

Formulas used

V=IR
P=IV
P=V^2/R